# Proper use of @@Error in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Taking any example for SQL Server 2000 documentation, or something like

```
Use Northwind
Go


Alter Procedure spu_UpdateOrderDetails(
@ProductID Int, 
@OrderId Int,
@ErrorCode Int OutPut,
@ErrorMessage Varchar(100) Output
)
As

UPDATE [Order Details]
SET ProductID = @ProductID
WHERE OrderID = @OrderId

Set @ErrorCode = @@ERROR

IF @ErrorCode <> 0
    Set @ErrorMessage = 'Some error ocurred'
GO


Declare @MyErrorCode Int
Declare @MyErrorMsg Varchar(100)

Exec spu_UpdateOrderDetails 999, 10248, @MyErrorCode OutPut, @MyErrorMsg OutPut

Print @MyErrorCode
Print @MyErrorMsg
```

This will cause a Foreign Key error, and I wll print the @MyErrorMsg properly.
But I still get the ugly Foreign Key error.

Now, if I run from within my application, it could be Delphi or Visual Studio, I still get the ugly error message, too.

How am I supposed to "trap" an error, so that I show my custom error to the user?

(I know newer SQL Server versions provides Try/Catch, but this is SQL Server 2000)

Comment: Read the Bible on SQL Server 2000 error handling and see if it helps: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a transaction, and roll it back it if errors, commit if success:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spu_UpdateOrderDetails
AS

DECLARE @ErrorCode int
       --,@myRowCount int
       ,@ProductID  
       ,@OrderId 
       --,@ErrorMessage Varchar(100) Output


SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRAN 
    UPDATE [Order Details]
    SET ProductID = @ProductID
    WHERE OrderID = @OrderId

    SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR--, @myRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
    IF @ErrorCode != 0 GOTO HANDLE_ERROR

COMMIT TRAN -- No Errors, so go ahead
RETURN 0

HANDLE_ERROR:
ROLLBACK TRAN
RETURN @ErrorCode
GO
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that still returns the ugly Foreign Key error to the client. I think the answer is : there's no clean solution, as far as I read the article provided by mellamokb.